# Refresh page using pull-down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a script that provides several different views of information pulled from a database.  The first merely shows the quantity of a given product sold each month, the second displays sales, the third shows profits, and the last consists of percentages calculated using profits and sales.  I currently use query strings to show this information, as illustrated below.

```
if(isset($_GET["reporttype"])){
    if($_GET["reporttype"] == "sales"){
        $isSalesView = true;
    }
    //Other types are handled here
}
```

What I want to do is implement a pull-down menu that features the four report types, and upon selection, changes the URL and refreshes the page to reflect the selection.  I've implemented the menu, and I've added some JS code:

```
$("#reportType").live("change",function(){
    if($(this).val() && $(this).val()>0){
        <?php
        if($isCustomerReport){?>
            location.href = "merchsalestemp.php?customerid=<?php echo $customerID; ?>&monthlyview=" + $(this).val();
        <?php
        }else if($isSingleItem){?>
            location.href = "merchsalestemp.php?itemid=<?php echo $itemID; ?>&monthlyview=" + $(this).val();
        <?php
        }else{?>                            
            location.href = "merchsalestemp.php?monthlyview=" + $(this).val();
        <?php
        };?>
    }
});
```

The `if` statements inside the block are for additional views for other purposes unrelated to the matter at hand.  I've tried selecting an option from the menu after uploading the completed file to the server but nothing happens.  What can I do to fix this problem?  The only other thing that comes to mind is that I'd implement links at the top of the page for each of these views, but I imagine that's a poor solution and wouldn't look good.

EDIT: I neglected to include the pull-down menu code.

```
<b>Select Report:</b> 
<select id="reportType" name="Option" style="width:250px; font-size:12px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    <option value="">Select report type</option>
    <option value="quantity">Monthly quantity</option>
    <option value="sales">Monthly sales</option>
    <option value="profit">Monthly profits</option>
    <option value="margin">Monthly gross margins</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with your `onchange` handler:

```
if($(this).val() && $(this).val()>0){
```

Your values are not numbers but strings ("quantity", "sales", etc.). Try this instead:

```
if($(this).val() && $(this).val() !== ''){
```

Comment: Perfect, that did it.